# Simple Python Pause/Resume

Tags: python, python-3.x, hotkeys, resume, pause

I was trying to pause/resume a task using hotkey, wrote the program bellow which is working fine while hitting Pause hotkey, but resume is not working. I guess I did some logical errors and need your expert advice to overcome that. Here is the script I wrote

```
import keyboard


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.run = True
        keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+alt+p", self.set_run)
        keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+alt+r", self.set_run_r)

    def set_run(self):
        self.run = False

    def set_run_r(self):
        self.run = True

    def start(self):
        val = 1
        while self.run:
            val += 1
            print("running ", val)

        keyboard.wait("esc")


Test().start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import keyboard
import sys



class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val=1
        self.run = True
        keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+alt+p", self.set_run)
        keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+alt+r", self.set_run_r)

    def set_run(self):
        self.run = False

    def set_run_r(self):
        self.run = True

    def start(self):
        self.val += 1
        print(self.val)
        return


test= Test()
try:
        while True:
            if test.run:
                test.start()
            else:
                pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     sys.exit()
```

Comment: No @Gaurav, your answer isn't correct. `self.start()` in `set_run_r()` can restart the program but not resume. Also, in that case, the pause will not wok any more.

Comment: Yes Sorry For the Typo. It will be in `self.set_run_r()`

Comment: Why The Pause Will not Works ?

Comment: Buddy, just run your code and check if works as expected

Comment: You need to add event listener also, i am updating code in half hour.

Comment: Hey Buddy Sorry For the delay, Actually was not able to find out what was the issue in that, now this work prefectly @IFightCode